# Intersection of XML nodes

Tags: xml, scala, lift, templating

Suppose we have a lot of similar, but not equal xml nodes. For example:

```
<div id = "a" class = "a b"><span>same</span><span>difference</span></div>
<div id = "b" class = "a b"><span>same</span></div>
```

I want to take intersection, i.e. common parts (both attributes and nodes) of them.

In this example it will be:

```
<div class = "a b"><span>same</span></div>
```

How to implement this in Scala? Is there any common way to do that?